# Asp.Net MVC Razor, combining global and local *.css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I got 'global.css' which is referenced in my 'layout' through `@Url.Content(path_to_css_file)`. Then I wanna some of my views to contain their own *.css. Which is the right way to achieve this? I've tried just to `<style></style>` each view, but that seems to be quite far from best solution, doesnt it?

Comment: add a head tag to your page and insert your stylesheet into it.

Comment: Did you receive your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use ViewBag to add your views in addition to your layout page.

Add something like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.LayoutStyle != null)
{
    <link href="@ViewBag.LayoutStyle" rel="stylesheet"/>
}
```

To your layout file after the global.css and in the views that you want to add a second css file after your global style, just set the `ViewBag.LayoutStyle` value to the URL of the css file.

This way you will have the opportunity to use a global css file and based on the view that you are loading you can load different css files overriding the global css based on your view.

Answer (score -1):

The best Approach is using bundles for referencing styles and scripts.
So in BundleConfig class in App_Start folder Add :

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/myglobalcss").Include(
"~/Content/global.css"
));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/mylocalcss").Include(
"~/Content/local.css"
));
```

then in your _Layout.cshtml `<head>` tag write this line:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/myglobalcss")
```

and for example in your Index.cshtml view add this line

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/mylocalcss")
```

which will render local.css specifically in your index view. actually you can reference more than one *.css file in each bundle and use them whereever you need.